# How to determine the text of a shape in PowerPoint using VBA

Tags: vba, powerpoint, msgbox

I simply want to grab text from a shape and display it somewhere else (Textbox, MsgBox...)

I know this isn't correct but hopefully you can grasp the concept from this.

```
msgbox ("Do you want to overwrite " & slide1.slot1.value &, 36, "?")

slot1 = shapename
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What type of image is the first question that comes to mind. But I believe [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/326775/Read-Text-From-scanned-image-using-VB-net) will point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 6):

Assuming that you're looking for the text in a shape named Slot1 on Slide 1 of the currently active presentation:

```
Msgbox ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes("Slot1").TextFrame.TextRange.Text
```